# knn algorithm error percentage

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, knn

I have developed knn algorithm for my data set. My data set contains 5000 *17 values. In this data set , I divide my data as 4000 for validation and 1000 for training.
My question is  at the end my error percentage is 0.0158 for training data.Does it means my algorithm is good for knn OR Did ı made a mistake? What do you think for my algorithm?

Comment: I assume your error percentage is 1.58%? If it was 0.0158%, that would be a fantastic result. I'd say 1.5% is a very good result, but it depends a bit on the data and the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Evaluating k-NN on the training set is quite dangerous, unless you do it correctly.  The reason is that each element is its own nearest neighbor.  Hence, the algorithm is cheating.

You don't specify what "k" is.  Obviously, if k = 1, then the nearest neighbor is the item itself (or perhaps an item with the same key values).

So, if you are writing the code yourself, for each training instance, you should exclude it from the set of neighbors.  You can do this manually.  Or, you can just evaluate the algorithm on the validation set and ignore the results on the training set.

Actually, for any algorithm, you should generally not use the training set for validation, if that is possible.

Comment: Actually, I did not include the point itself by changing its values every time.  I just find k-points which has minimum distances to current point. I give values based on  values of these k points. I just get smaller error in the first run and it makes me suspicious about my algorithm.

Comment: @Muaa2404 . . . Think about that.  The distance from a point in the training set to itself is 0, so it is always included in the nearest neighbors (or at least a candidate if there are ties).  That is cheating.